# fast concatenation of strings

Tags: python, string, numpy, cython

I have a two-dimensional 0/1-array, `X`. Each column represents a particular letter. For each row, I want to join those letters whose value in `X` takes the value 1.

E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
abc = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],dtype=str)
X = np.random.randint(0,2,(5,abc.shape[0]))

res = [np.string_.join('',abc[row==1]) for row in X]
```

This is fine, only that this particular task is the bottleneck of my code. Hence, I tried to move it to cython without success, largely due to my very limited understanding of strings and chars and more. Below the code for reference, but it is just bad. For once, it does not quite return what I want (the chars would have to be converted to Python strings, for example) and, more worrisome, I believe the code is not stable.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython 

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free 

def join_c(int[:,:] idx, bytes abc):

    cdef:
        size_t i, j, count
        int n = idx.shape[0]
        int m = idx.shape[1]

        char *arr = <char *>malloc((n*(m+1))*sizeof(char))

    count = 0
    try:        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                if idx[i,j] == 1:

                    arr[count] = abc[j]
                    count +=1 

            arr[count] = ','
            count+=1

        return [x for x in arr]

    finally:
        free(arr)
```

I would like to see how one could do this in cython but I am happy with any other fast solution.

Comment: Are all elements in `abc` always single characters?

Comment: yes, they are all single letters from the english alphabet.

Comment: Your NumPy code is joining the strings with `''`. So why is your attempted Cython code adding `','` characters? Do you want comma-separate characters, or just concatenated characters? Also, what is the `[x for x in arr]` at the end intended to do? If you just want to turn something into a list, use `list(arr)`, but why would you want to return a list here? Your goal is to return a string, right?

Comment: you are right, the return value is not what I want. The ``','`` is there to let me know where the row starts. Each row will potentially have a different number of strings, depending on the number of 1s in the respective row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one string-array based solution -

```
def join_singlechars(abc, X):
    # Get mask
    mask = X==1

    # Get start, stop indices for splitting the concatenated string later on
    idx = np.r_[0,mask.sum(1).cumsum()]

    # Get concatenated string
    n = idx[-1] #sum of 1s in mask          
    s = np.broadcast_to(abc, X.shape)[mask].tostring()
    # Or np.broadcast_to(abc, X.shape)[mask].view('S'+str(n))[0]

    return [s[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])] # finally split
```

Sample run -

```
In [229]: abc
Out[229]: array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='|S1')

In [230]: X
Out[230]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])

In [231]: join_singlechars(abc, X)
Out[231]: ['ACF', 'ABDE', 'ACD', 'ABDEF', 'ABCF']
```

Timings on a large `5000 x 5000` array case -

```
In [321]: abc = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],dtype=str)
     ...: abc = np.resize(abc,5000)
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: X = np.random.randint(0,2,(5000,5000))

In [322]: %timeit [np.string_.join('',abc[row==1]) for row in X]
1 loop, best of 3: 648 ms per loop

In [323]: %timeit join_singlechars(abc, X)
1 loop, best of 3: 209 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice. The improvement becomes even more significant when increasing the number of rows. In my case the number of rows tend towards a million. ``X = np.random.randint(0,2,(1000000,abc.shape[0]))``. Timing: ``%timeit res = [np.string_.join('',abc[row==1]) for row in X]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.79 s per loop`` vs. ``%timeit res_a = join_singlechars(abc,X)
1 loop, best of 3: 290 ms per loop``

Comment: Still, I would be curious how one would do that in cython.

Comment: @user3820991 Sorry, I don't have a cython solution on this.